# Python BeautifulSoup returning incorrect html code

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get movie names from imdb list my problem is instead of returning the English name that appear in google chrome inspect element it return the Japanese name.

***Note:*** I tried all BeautifulSoup parsers

***Code:***

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page=requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/list/ls040141830/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
name = soup.find('h3','lister-item-header')
print(name)
```

result:

```
<h3 class="lister-item-header">
<span class="lister-item-index unbold text-primary">1.</span>
<a href="/title/tt0245429/?ref_=ttls_li_tt">Sen to Chihiro no kamikakushi</a>
<span class="lister-item-year text-muted unbold">(2001)</span>
</h3>
```

expected result as show in page source:
[image]

as you can see the name in english but im getting it in japanese any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Maybe, after initial page loading, some java script executes and translates local name to English, and in browser you already see it in English?

Comment: Are you trying to get imdb pages with an ip address from japan?

Comment: @kosist yes in broser i see it in english

Comment: @MrAlihoseiny no my normal ip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems if you visit imdb from a non-browser client, imdb will translate the movie names into the original language. You should be able to fix it by add the [Accept-Language](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) header to requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}
page=requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/list/ls040141830/', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
name = soup.find('h3','lister-item-header')
print(name)
```